# How to diagnose or rule out an Nvidia driver issue?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm getting freezes, which don't happen on Windows. The mouse stops moving and the PC becomes completely unresponsive. ALT + Print Screen + REISUB doesn't work either.

I'm having one more issue, only in Ubuntu - the display flickers. The only thing that fixes it is turning off dithering in the Nvidia driver, but that reduces the picture quality too much for my taste.

The bottom line is I think there is something wrong with my Nvidia driver. While writing this from my laptop, I rebooted my PC and after entering my password it froze again.

Is there any error log I can see to start diagnosing this?

This is the syslog from the last crash:

```
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC anacron[1011]: Job `cron.daily' started
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC anacron[3111]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2023-02-21
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC anacron[1011]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC anacron[1011]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Feb 21 14:13:32 PC systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1209]: (EE) event3  - Logitech G305: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 21ms, your system is too slow
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC dbus-daemon[1017]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.72' (uid=0 pid=1032 comm="/usr/lib/snapd/snapd " label="unconfined")
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC dbus-daemon[1017]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC snapd[1032]: storehelpers.go:769: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core20", "firefox", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gtk-common-themes", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration"
Feb 21 14:13:36 PC snapd[1032]: autorefresh.go:551: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Feb 21 14:13:37 PC wpa_supplicant[1039]: wlp7s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Feb 21 14:13:52 PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1209]: (EE) event3  - Logitech G305: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 22ms, your system is too slow
Feb 21 14:14:06 PC systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 21 14:15:57 PC kernel: [  452.771543] gnome-terminal-[2919]: segfault at 55a58b494276 ip 00007f7fb74dc740 sp 00007fffb6f59e88 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.7200.4[7f7fb74b2000+33000]
Feb 21 14:15:57 PC kernel: [  452.771557] Code: ff fc 03 00 00 77 33 48 c1 ef 02 48 8d 05 18 5a 02 00 48 8b 3c f8 48 81 fe fc 03 00 00 76 28 48 83 e6 fc 31 c0 48 85 ff 74 33 <f6> 47 16 04 74 05 48 85 f6 75 2d 31 c0 c3 66 90 48 83 e7 fc 48 81
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC systemd[1]: Started crash report submission.
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC whoopsie[3179]: [14:15:58] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC whoopsie-upload-all[3178]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 21 14:15:58 PC systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1]: Started crash report submission.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1179]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1179]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1179]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Consumed 6.072s CPU time.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1179]: vte-spawn-1a2e3a34-8b41-4731-8f27-fc5911ac6ad8.scope: Consumed 1.195s CPU time.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC whoopsie[3186]: [14:15:59] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC whoopsie-upload-all[3185]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 21 14:15:59 PC systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Feb 21 14:16:01 PC systemd[1179]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Feb 21 14:16:01 PC dbus-daemon[1212]: [session uid=1000 pid=1212] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.102' (uid=1000 pid=3195 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Feb 21 14:16:01 PC systemd[1179]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Feb 21 14:16:01 PC dbus-daemon[1212]: [session uid=1000 pid=1212] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Feb 21 14:16:01 PC systemd[1179]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Feb 21 14:16:01 PC systemd[1179]: Started VTE child process 3218 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 3198.
Feb 21 14:16:56 PC gnome-shell[1500]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5583ef6bc340] is on because it needs an allocation.
Feb 21 14:16:56 PC gnome-shell[1500]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5583f186ef40] is on because it needs an allocation.
Feb 21 14:16:56 PC gnome-shell[1500]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5583f1872da0] is on because it needs an allocation.
```

Comment: @guiverc it's 22.04, edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the PC freezes only when I leave it idle - no music playing and I don't move the mouse. I googled "ubuntu freezes when idle" and found this:

> There is a bug in the kernel that causes ryzen cpus to freeze when they enter a certain c-state (power mode). Usually it happens when the computer has been idle for a while and the kernel atempts to put the cpu in a low-power mode, only a reset will wake up the cpu again.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qlbss5/ubuntu_2004_freezes_when_left_idle_for_a_while/

I disabled C-State from the BIOS and haven't had any freezes so far. I installed the latest Ubuntu version, why this bug still exists I don't know.